# Dual monitors, second monitor not working

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors

I have recently bought a new PC with two monitors. The first time I connected both monitors, it worked fine but since then after a restart, the second (non primary) monitor does not turn on even though I see the on light flashing but it does not say "No signal"

If I make the scond monitor my primary monitor, it starts working fine but the first monitor turns off.

I have a GTX1060 with one monitor connecting via HDMI (secondary monitor) and one via DVI (primary monitor).

If I use Nvidia control panel to span the screen across both monitors, that works after which if I change it back to dual monitors, both start working. But after a restart, secondary monitor if off again.

I will be trying to update drivers this weekend but apart from that I don't know what to try. Any help appreciated.

**Edit**

Using Windows 10

Comment: You need to say what Operating System you are using.

Comment: You can save profiles in the nVidia control center, which would let you hit a hotkey after reboot to fix it by restoring the working setting, until such time as you can fix the startup state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the the Nvidia control panel was considering the monitor connect via HDMI as being my primary monitor but I had set the monitor connected via DVI as primary. Swapping the cable on the monitors, the HDMI to my primary and DVI to my secondary monitor, fixed the problem for me.

Both monitors now turn on as expected when restarting my machine.